# What Happened to the Original Cybermen?

Tags: doctor-who

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to the Cybermen in our universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3819/what-happened-to-the-cybermen-in-our-universe)

Like many people, I never had a chance to watch the original *Doctor Who* and got started with the new series and I've been catching up along the way.  I always knew a little about the series, but just never had a chance to watch it.  So I had heard of Daleks and Cybermen, and knew that the Cybermen that Lumic created were not the original Cybermen.  I remember the Doctor saying, "It's happening again," when he sees Lumic's Cybermen.

What happened to the original Cybermen from the original series?  Were they finally destroyed?

Comment: @TangoOversway -- Your question is phrased better, but it's substantially the same question, and [Tony Meyer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/108/tony-meyer) gave a pretty detailed answer to it.

Comment: Hmmmm...I do search, so it puzzles me when I miss something, but I could just zone out while scanning titles.  It looks like it'll probably get closed anyway, then.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put = The cybermen were never destroyed completely and definitively in the original series run.

The last time the Cybermen appeared in the original run was "Silver Nemesis".  Although their fleet was entirely destroyed, it seems unlikely that it represented the whole of the Cybermen in the universe then or later.

As early as the 2nd Doctor, the Cybermen were shown to be distributed in many disconnected groups.  In "Silver Nemesis" (7th doctor) they were a major power in the galaxy with at least 12 fleets.

In "Revenge of the Cybermen" (4th doctor) and "Earthshock" (5th doctor) they were the last survivors of a nearly dead species.  These two groups could have been just isolated remnants of a much larger diaspora.

I don't know if there is a connection between the Lumic Cybermen and the Mondas Cybermen.