# Are any of the cybermen in the revived Doctor Who from Mondas?

Tags: doctor-who

We see the cyber head in **Dalek**, this appears to be from the disco edition Cybermen from Mondas rather than Cybus Industries.

Are any of the later appearances from this source or are they all from the alternative universe versions?

[image: funk disco cyberman]

Comment: Related: [What happened to the Cybermen in our universe?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3819/31394)

Comment: I think Word of Writer says the Cybermen from the Smith era are all Mondas cybermen, they just didn't bother changing the costume yet again.  Having trouble finding a source though.

Comment: This cyberman appears to be the one from the Tom Baker story "Revenge of the Cybermen", which is somewhat anachronistic since that story was set in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a comment in the Brilliant Book 2012 in which it's commented that the Cybermen of the Cyber Legion are Mandosian in origin.

http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Cyberman

> According to comments made in The Brilliant Book 2012, the Cybermen of
>   the Cyber Legions were the original Mondasian versions because,
>   despite having the Cybus-style suits, they lacked the "C" logo on
>   their chest. If so, the Cybus Industries Cybermen joined the Alliance
>   and the Cybermen that have appeared since then (without the "C" logos)
>   are the Mondasian models.

If you compare the chest logos for Cybus Cybermen with that of the Cybermen in episodes you will see that they are different.

Here is a photo of what Cybus Cybermen look like.

[image]

And here is a photo of the Cyberman from the episode A Good Man Goes to War.

[image]

As you can see the logo on their chest are completely different.  The first shows one with a C like logo and the other has no such logo just a circle.  The first set of Cybermen are from Cybus but the second set are not from Pete's Universe so they are more than likely the Mondasian variety.

Neil Gaiman who was the writer for a few of the episodes of Doctor Who had his own thoughts.

> Neil Gaiman, writer of The Doctor's Wife in Series 6 and Nightmare in
>   Silver in Series 7, has stated in an interview that he believed the
>   Cybermen in the "'Tom Baker' universe" had all but died out. That left
>   the Cybus Cybermen who had escaped the Void and ended up in Victorian
>   London, and were sent into the Time Vortex at the end of The Next
>   Doctor. Rather than be disintegrated as Jackson Lake predicted, they
>   were scattered through time and space and eventually encountered the
>   remnants of the Mondasian Cybermen, "and there was some cross-breeding
>   and interchange of technology, which is why you then get the ones that
>   look like, but actually aren't, the Cybus Cybermen." This is despite
>   the fact that all of the Cybermen in The Next Doctor were seen to be
>   blown to bits by Mercy Hartigan, unless there were more deeper within
>   the CyberKing. However, Gaiman includes no reference to this theory in
>   Nightmare in Silver.

Answer (score -2):

There was also a noted departure between Mondasian and Telosian Cybermen - Telos became the main planet of the Cybermen very early in the series' history.  Mondasian Cybermen were far more primitive in design - the Cybermen of Telos were more like the ones we now think of as the standard.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question